# How to append particular string to another string based on a specific string match?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to append `_123` if name has `_abc_0` or `_abc_1` or `_abc_#` where `# is any number of digits`. How can I write it in `if` condition?

```
name = "name_abc_0_any_chars"
if "_abc_<#any digit>" in name: #not sure what to write in place of <#any digit>
    name = name + "_123"
print "name: ", name
```

Output:

```
name: name_abc_0_any_chars_123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

If you want to test if a variable contains `_abc_#d`, use `re`:

```
import re

name = "name_abc_0_any_chars"
if re.findall('abc_\d+', name):
    name += '_123'
```

Output:

```
'name_abc_0_any_chars_123'
```

Comment: But the name is not always `name_abc_0`, it can be `name_abc_0_read` or anything else after `_0`.

Comment: Just edited the question, sorry that I did not clarify it earlier.

Comment: @npatel Just to make clearer, is it always one digit? I'll update the answer right away

Comment: Your solution doesn't even compare `_abc_`, it only looks for the digit. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: It can be any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution without regex, you could use the `any()` function. E.g.

```
a = ['_abc_0', '_abc_1', '_abc_2', '_abc_3', '_abc_4', '_abc_5', '_abc_6', '_abc_7', '_abc_8', '_abc_9']
name = "name_abc_34_other_characters"

if any(x in name for x in a):
    name += "_123"

print("name: ", name)
```

Output:

```
name:  name_abc_34_other_characters_123
```